# Handling images for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc in Ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

When developing for Android using Android Studio, you have to create your images in various resolutions (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc) and then the application would choose the right one based on you device.

But now I'm learning Ionic 2 and I would like to hear from experienced people how they handle it...

I couldn't find any good examples on Google or courses.

I could create them in the higher resolution and then let the webview handle the resizing. But I think low end devices would suffer a great performance hit. Am I right?

I could also somehow create different stylesheets for each resolution, but I would need to have methods to get the screen resolution, dpi and physical size.

What would be the best practices used to handle this?